# Исправление лексических ошибок

Tags: лексика

Гражданка Сидорова Н .Ф. обратилась с заявлением о разводе брака. 2. Нужно сказать должное идее прези дента. 3. Сообщаем наши реквизиты: 33 Москва, 123298. Ул. На родного Ополчения. 4. Не нужно из этого факта строить проблему. 5. В заключение хотелось бы напомнить, что в по строе нии всех известных зарубежных рынков государственные кре диты играют немалое значение. 6. Участники следственного эксперимента участвовали в судебных заседаниях. 7. После проведения рекламной компании на предприятии не осталось ни одной свободной вакансии. 8. Новый начальник отдела насаждает в коллективе порядок и дисциплину. 9. Золотая медаль была компенсацией за ее трудолюбие, усердие, настойчивость. 10. Многие современные молодые люди целеустремленно стремятся к своей цели

Answer (score 2):

1. Гражданка Сидорова Н .Ф. обратилась с заявлением о **расторжении** брака. 2. Нужно **отдать** должное идее президента. 3. Сообщаем **наш адрес**: 33 Москва, 123298. Ул. Народного Ополчения. 4. Не нужно из этого факта **создавать** проблемы. 5. В заключение хотелось бы напомнить, что в построении всех известных зарубежных рынков государственные кредиты играют **немаловажную роль**. 6. *Затрудняюсь найти ошибку*. 7. После проведения рекламной **кампании** на предприятии не осталось ни одной **вакансии**. 8. *Не вижу ошибки, но, возможно, если действия начальника не связаны с принуждением - а скорее всего, так оно и есть, - стоит сформулировать предложение следующим образом:* "Новый начальник отдела прививает членам коллектива дисциплину и приучает к порядку". 9. Золотая медаль была **наградой** за ее трудолюбие, усердие, настойчивость. 10. Многие современные молодые люди **упорно** стремятся к своей цели.

Answer (score 2):

6.Участники следственного эксперимента были приглашены (или вызваны)на судебные заседания.

Comment: Вполне можно сказать, мне кажется, что они участвовали в судебных заседаниях, если Арбитражный процессуальный кодекс Российской Федерации (http://official.academic.ru/18897/Предварительное_судебное_заседание_в_арбитражном_процессе) считает возможной такую формулировку.

Comment: Я думаю, "участники участвовали" не совсем правильно.

Comment: Да, с этой точки зрения Вы правы.

Comment: @ЛЕНЧИК, если людей пригласили или вызвали, то это не значит, что они участвовали, то есть смысл при таком "исправлении" немного меняется. Я нахожу более удачными следующие варианты: 1) "Задействованные в следственном эксперименте люди участвовали в судебных заседаниях"; 2) Участники следственного эксперимента присутствовали на судебных заседаниях".